# I want to use h2 database and scripts on my application but cannot connect it

Tags: database, spring-boot

I have my dependencies set and app.properties

```
pring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
#Spring data JPA properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb:MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.format_sql=true

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

spring.thymeleaf.cache = false
```

in my resource directory I have two files table-script.sql for creating tables 
and data-scripts.sql dumping insert statement but what can I do to get this database running on my console, help guys thanks and this is spring boot no other config file I needed or data source bean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
@Profile("test")
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource(value = {"classpath:test.properties"})
    static class ConfigTest {


        @Autowired
        private Environment env;

        @Bean(name = "dataSource")
        public DataSource dataSourceTest() {
            return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                    .generateUniqueName(true)
                    .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                    .setScriptEncoding("UTF-8")
                    .addScripts("schema.sql", "data.sql")
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapterTest() {
            HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
            adapter.setShowSql(false);
            adapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);
            adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
            adapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
            return adapter;
        }
    }
```

This is how I configured mine, as the Inmemory database names are auto generated I couldn't make the property file provide either. I had to let Java and Spring do that itself

> table-script.sql

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (
  id          INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  name        VARCHAR(255)                   NOT NULL,
  field_1    TEXT,
  field_2    TEXT,
  field_3    INT                            NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (
      id          INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  name        VARCHAR(255)                   NOT NULL,
  field_1    TEXT,
  field_2    TEXT,
  field_3    INT                            NOT NULL
);
```

> Here is sample folder structure

```html
src
|--- main
    |--- java
        |--- com.project.root # classpath: <- genarally pointing here
            |--- confing
                |--- AppConfig.java #Above file
    |--- resources
         |--- table-script.sql
```

That's kind of all to it. Rest is handled by Spring. It run that file when it creating the random database.

Comment: so u have class path test.properties what is in your class path

Comment: That file is empty. `classpath` is normally the root of your project

Comment: also in spring boot I don't need to create h2 SQL query ? because I want to populate my database and view it in console

Comment: Thats, tricky, I couldn't do that with mine as H2 only allow one connection to the database at a time. So you won't be able to view on console and connect to the app at the same time. There's a way however, if you can find it

Comment: And I'm populating mine with this `.addScripts("schema.sql", "data.sql")` line, So I control it ether way

Comment: mm thanks but .add scripts is a method ?never seen this before

Comment: Yeah, since its a in memory db, I use two files to create a DB and Tables and add some data to it, every time I run the app. You can give it as many files as you need.

Comment: so this add script is written in application property right ?

Comment: It's just SQL files in you `resources` folder

Comment: yes I have those sql file mine are table-scripts.sql

Comment: but I should also add .addscript=("table-script.sql" , data-script.sql)

Comment: @valentine in your case it&#39;s just `table-script.sql`. If you want rum more, they must be in your `resources` folder.

Comment: bro can u send me an example code to see how add scripts is used